# Azure Stream Analytics timestamp for window end

Tags: streaming, azure-stream-analytics, windowing

I am running some test jobs on Azure Stream Analytics running this query:

```
SELECT System.Timestamp AS ts, Collect()
INTO output−queue
FROM input-hub TIMESTAMP BY tapp
GROUP BY HoppingWindow(second , 4 , 2)
```

and it turns out that, in some cases, the timestamp for the window end is a multiple of the window *slide* parameter, but sometimes not.

For example, with `slide = 2` you get this window closing timestamps:

```
2016-08-04T10:36:40.0000000Z
2016-08-04T10:36:42.0000000Z
2016-08-04T10:36:44.0000000Z
2016-08-04T10:36:46.0000000Z
2016-08-04T10:36:48.0000000Z
```

Or, in the case `slide = 5`:

```
2016-08-04T14:55:15.0000000Z
2016-08-04T14:55:20.0000000Z
2016-08-04T14:55:25.0000000Z
2016-08-04T14:55:30.0000000Z
```

This is true even for different *slide* values (e.g. 2, 3, 4, 6, ...). Moreover, it is *always* true! No matter when the job has been started.

There are values instead (such as 7, 11) that does not follow this rule.

Can somebody answer why does this happen?
I am wondering how does Azure SA decides when to open the first window.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

There are different kinds of windows (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835019.aspx) for more details).

First, window starts/ends do not depend on the job start time.

**Tumbling** and **Hopping** windows are best to think of, logically, as partitioning the timeline itself. For example applying Tumbling window of *1 minute* will make results to appear only at time values which are mod of 1 min, i.e. *2:00pm*, *2:01pm*, etc.

Note that not every 1 minute boundary must have window result, it rather depends on the computation.

**Sliding** window can produce output at any point on the timeline, and unlike tumbling and hopping windows, ***does*** depend on the timestamps of the input events. Best way to think of sliding windows is that window may end at any input event and starts *slide* amount of time before that event. In other words for each event window will include all events occurred at or up to slide time before it.

Hope this helps.